# New Relic: JS error monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I am trying to enable the Browser monitoring provided by New Relic in my Rails app. I followed the steps listed in the [docs](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/installation-configuration/browser-settings-ui-options-browser-monitoring#enabling) - which is basically turning on the feature within the New Relic settings for the app. But not all errors are being logged within the JS Errors tab. My questions is do I need to do some changes within Rails app to include new relic agent on the page? I currently have `browser_monitoring.auto_instrument: false` in my `newrelic.yml` because I use the manual way of doing this for some specific pages. Is this property also responsible for doing the error monitoring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [auto instrumentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/features/page-load-timing-ruby#auto_instrumentation) is what injects NewRelic's JavaScript into your page to analyze performance and report errors. The default is `true`. If you've turned it off, you'll only catch errors from pages where you're manually including it.

If you turn it back on, you can disable it on certain pages where you're doing things manually using [`newrelic_ignore`](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ignoring-specific-transactions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe you have sufficiently answered the original question. Though, I am still not able to see the logs. On further debugging, I found that NewRelic::Agent.browser_timing_header call is actually throwing undefined method `browser_timing_header' for NewRelic::Agent:Module exception. I was expecting this call to actually inject the script for browser monitoring. I am wondering if you have any clue on that.

Comment: @shreyj Wish I did, but I haven't seen that before. I'd recommend [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), perhaps with a link to this one for context.